# how to create a function in python that prints out uppercase words

Tags: python

I'm absolutely new to programming with python but I'm really willing to learn it. This community was highly suggested by my lecturer so I'll give it a try.

Okay so I have a sentence with upper and lowercase words and I want to write a function that only prints out the words that start with an uppercase letter.

This is what I got so far:

```
s = """Hey! Hast du schon gesehen,
    wie einfach es ist, in Python zu programmieren?
    Es ist viel einfacher als on den meisten
    anderen Sprachen, die man so kennt."""

def print_all_Uppercased(s):
    for word in s:
        if word[0].isupper():
            print word

print_all_Uppercased(s)
```

Thing is, this only prints out the single uppercase letters. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: `[word for word in s.split() if word[0].isupper()]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're pretty close.

```
for word in s.split():
    if word[0].isupper()
```

You're not iterating over words, but letters. [`split`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.split) first to obtain the desired result.

You can also trim this a little from a function into a single [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
[word for word in s.split() if word[0].isupper()]
```

That's handy if you want to do more than just print them out immediately.

Comment: works perfectly, can't believe I was so close ugh. Thanks!

Comment: @Juls Be sure you check one of the answers that helped you to 'accept' it. That's how we mark answers solved here.

Comment: ah I see, will do! Thanks again

Answer (score 5):

You truly are so close! The problem here is that `for word in s` unfortunately just selects every single character in `s` and not **every word** in `s`.

If you run this loop on it's own and `print` the contents, you'll see the results are just characters.

```
for word in s: print word

# Prints:
H
e
... # (omitting the rest of the characters)
```

So your function is just checking *each individual character* checking if that character is uppercase with `if word[0].isupper():` (remember each character can be considered a list with one element) and then printing it.

In order to fix this, you'll need to first make a `list` of the words from your string `s`.

This is easily done by using [`split()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) `s` which splits the string on spaces and returns the list containing the words. Then, you can apply your `isupper()` call to check for each word in the list.

```
def print_all_Uppercased(s):
    for word in s.split():
        if word[0].isupper():
            print word
```

Which now successfully prints:

```
Hey!
Hast
Python
Es
Sprachen,
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! Works perfectly!

Comment: You're welcome, Juls. As Two-Bit Alchemist mentioned, mark one of these answers as Accepted for other users to know what solved your problem. :-)